# Therem 3.17 in Baby Rudin: The Analogous Result

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Here's Theorem 3.17 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, third edition.

> Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $E$ denote the set of all the subsequential limits of $\{s_n \}$ (in the extended real number system). Let $s^* = \sup E$. Then $s^*$ has the following two properties.
>
> (a) $s^* \in E$.
>
> (b) If $x > s^*$, there is an integer $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $s_n < x$.
>
> Moreover, $s^*$ is the only number with the properties (a) and (b).

I've given a my reading of Rudin's proof. Here's the link. [Theorem 3.17 in Baby Rudin: Infinite Limits and Upper and Lower Limits of Real Sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757735/theorem-3-17-in-baby-rudin-infinite-limits-and-upper-and-lower-limits-of-real-s)

Now I would like to state and prove the analogous result which Rudin refers to after the statement.

So here's the statement.

> Let $\{s_n \}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $E$ denote the set of all the subsequential limits of $\{s_n \}$ (in the extended real number system), and let $s_* = \inf E$. Then
>
> (a) $s_* \in E$.
>
> (b) If $x< s_*$, there is an integer $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $s_n > x$.
>
> Moreover, $s_8$ is the only number with the properties (a) and (b).

And, here's my proof.

> If $s_* = - \infty$, then, for every real number $M$, there is an element $x_M \in E$ such that $x_M < M$, and since this element $x_M$ is a subsequential limit of $\{s_n\}$, there is a subsequence of $\{s_n \}$ all but finitely many of whose terms are less than $M$. Thus, there is a natural natural number $n_1$ such that $s_{n_1} < -1$. And, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k > 1$, we can find a natural number $n_k$ such that that $n_k > n_{k-1}$ and $s_{n_k} < -k$. And, the subsequence $\{s_{n_k}\}$ diverges to $- \infty$. So $-\infty \in E$.
>
> If $s_*$ is finite (i.e. real), then the set $E$ is bounded below in $\mathbb{R}$, and for every $\delta > 0$, we can find an element $x_\delta \in E$ such that $s_* \leq x_\delta < s_* + \delta$. Now as $x_\delta$ is a subsequential limit of $\{s_n \}$, there are infinitely many terms of $\{s_n\}$ in the half open interval $[x_\delta, s_* + \delta ) \subset [s_* , s_* + \delta)$. So for $\delta = 1$, there is some natural number $n_1$ such that $s_* \leq s_{n_1} < s_* + 1$, and, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k > 1$, we can find a natural number $n_k$ such that $n_k > n_{k-1}$ and $s_* \leq s_{n_k} < s_* + \frac 1 k$. Then the subsequence $\{s_{n_k}\}$ converges to $s_*$, showing that $s_* \in E$.
>
> If $s_* = +\infty$, then no real number or $- \infty$ can be a seubseuqntial limit of $\{s_n \}$. So, for every real number $M$, there is a positive real number $\delta_M$ such that the segment $(M-\delta_M, M+\delta_M)$ contains only finitely many terms of the sequence $\{s_n\}$. And there is a real number $t$ such that there are only finitely many terms of $\{s_n\}$ in the infinite open interval $(-\infty, t)$. Moreover, if there were some segment (i.e. finite open interval) $(a, b)$ containing infinitely many terms of $\{s_n\}$, then some subsequence of $\{s_n\}$ would be bounded and thus would have a subsequence converging to a real number in the interval $[a,b]$, and that real number would thus be a subsequential limit of $\{s_n \}$, contradicting the definition of $s_*$. So, for every real number $M$, there would be at most finitely many terms in $(-\infty, M + 1 ]$. Thus there would be a natural number $n_1$ such that $s_{n_1} > 1$, and for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k > 1$ there would be a natural number $n_k$ such that $n_k > n_{k-1}$ and $s_{n_k} > k$. Therefore the subsequence $\{s_{n_k}\}$ diverges to $+ \infty$ and hence $+\infty \in E$.
>
> This establishes (a) in all cases.
>
> If $x < s_*$ and if there are infinitely many $s_n \leq x$, then the range of some subsequence of $\{s_n\}$ would be contained in $(-\infty, x]$, and this subsequence (depending on whether it is unbounded below or bounded) would in turn have a subsequence which either diverges to $-\infty$ or converges to a real number $\leq x$; in either case we would have an element $y \in E$ such that $y \leq x < s_*$, a contradiction.
>
> Thus $s_*$ satisfies (a) and (b).
>
> To show the uniqueness, suppose there are two numbers $p$ and $q$ which satisfy (a) and (b) and suppose that $p < q$. Choose a real number $x$ such that $p < x < q$. As $q$ satisfies (b), there is an integer $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies that $s_n > x$. Thus, for $\delta \in (0, x-p)$, the neighborhood $(p-\delta, p+\delta)$ of $p$ contains only finitely many terms of $\{s_n\}$, which implies that $p$ cannot be a subsequential limit (in the extended real number system) of $\{s_n\}$, which contradicts (a).

Is this statement correct? And if so, is the proof correct? Or, are there any issues? How about my presentation?

Comment: The statement looks fine to me.

Comment: @Vim and what about the proof?

Comment: I don't have time to read it line by line. But if you do argue by analogue to Rudin's argument, I think it should be fine too.

Comment: Proof looks OK, but this seems a very weird way to characterize upper and lower limits $s^{*}, s_{*}$. That's why I don't like Rudin. He has a habit of overcomplicating simple stuff and the way he deals with $\limsup, \liminf$ is one evidence of that.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh you may be justified in holding your opinion, but I think Rudin can be a good choice if you've already had some exposure to abstract mathematics. What is your choice for a book on mathematical analysis, the same stuff as is covered in Baby Rudin?

Comment: I prefer books which are easy to understand and avoid too much symbolism. my own knowledge of analysis comes from two books: A Course of Pure Mathematics by G. H. Hardy (old classic) and Mathematical Analysis by Tom. M. Apostol. Plus one should always read the book which is advised by the professor/instructor of the course.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh the one by Apostol I too like; in fact, that book covers a lot more stuff than does Rudin. But in August last year the two bags I was carrying with me got snatched while I was traveling from Abbottabad to Peshawar, and the book was in one of those bags. That book has been published by Narosa, but I've still not been able to find it here in Pakistan.

Comment: You should search for an online copy. some ebook sites will provide it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes, I've got that already. But I would certainly like to have a printed copy, even if be that one published by Narosa. I've just not been able to locate it in the catalogs on the websites of the major booksellers of Pakistan.